# asp.net core MVC area routing, routevalue params for some areas

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a number of areas in my mvc app, and some of them require a route value, as a prefix to the whole route. like this...

mydomain.com/{routevalue}/{area}/{controller}/{action}/{id?}

however, there are a couple of areas which do not use this routevalue and thus I would like them to respond to 
mydomain.com/{area}/{controller}/{action}/{id?}

I am trying to construct some route templates which cover this requirement, but not having much luck.
I had initially added a new route for each area, such that the ones that didnt need the routevalue would not have that in the template.
this was working fine when running locally is IIS express, but as soon as I deployed to IIS on a server, none of these area routes was responding, and instead I was getting a 404..

here is my current config

```
routes.MapAreaRoute("YourAccountArea", "YourAccount", "YourAccount/{controller}/{action}/{id?}",
    defaults: new { area = "YourAccount", controller = "YourAccount", action = "Index" }); //<-- no product param on this area route

routes.MapAreaRoute("AboutYouArea", "AboutYou", "{product}/AboutYou/{controller}/{action}/{id?}",
    defaults: new { area = "AboutYou", product = "defaultproduct", controller = "AboutYou", action = "Index" });//<--this area does have the product prefix

routes.MapAreaRoute("SelectionArea", "Selection", "{product}/Selection/{controller}/{action}/{id?}",
    defaults: new { area = "Selection", controller = "SelectProduct", action = "Index" });//<--as does this

routes.MapRoute("default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");//<--standard route
```

I am wondering if I can slim this down at all, and actually get it to respond on the server? I do not currently have any `Area` or `Route` attributes on the controllers or actions (as I hadn't need them before)

edit:
i then tried this:

```
routes.MapRoute("areaNoProduct", "{area:exists}/{controller}/{action}/{id?}",
defaults: new { area = "YourAccount", controller = "YourAccount", action = "Index" });

routes.MapRoute(
   name: "areaRoute",
   template: "{product}/{area:exists}/{controller}/{action=index}/{id?}");

routes.MapRoute("default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

but not only does that pop the product as a querystring, but it doesnt generate the correct urls for actions, which I assume is the routing being incorrect

Answer (score 0):

I would go with the asp-tag-helpers
Have a try
http://www.davepaquette.com/archive/2015/06/01/mvc-6-anchor-tag-helper.aspx